# Can a 220V AC to 12V DC adapter be plugged into 120V mains?

Tags: electrical

I ordered a piece of equipment with a small low-RPM electric motor that came with DC adapter. It's marked

```
ANGEL
MODEL SG-4805
DC 12V
AC ADAPTOR
HA 10025-2003A
AC 220V 16VA
50/60Hz
DC 12V 850mA
```

Can it be plugged into 120V mains (safely, and without loss of performance)?

When I look around on the internet, I see some adapters that state the input like `INPUT: 100-240V` but this one does not give a range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would not be a good idea to try to plug it into 120V.

Internally, that adapter is likely to have one of 2 options.

Option 1: A simple transformer/rectifier/capaitor arrangement.
In this case, since the transformer windings ratio is fixed, you should expect to get about 6.5V out (12/220*120).
Although supplying a low voltage to your motor isn't likely to do much (if any) damage, it certainly won't perform as you'd like it to.
It will probably also be much easier to stall - which could lead to some damage to the motor and/or adapter.

Option 2: A switch-mode power supply.
In this case, the incoming mains AC is rectified & smoothed to high(ish)-voltage DC and this DC is then 'switched' through a much smaller transformer at a much higher frequency than the 50/60Hz mains (typically many 10s of kHz).
These circuits *can* be designed to operate from a very wide range of input voltages, but this is not always the case as it would likely increase the cost & complexity of the circuit.
If your adapter was designed for a wide input range if would probably be marked as such.

The fact that your adapter's specs include a 'VA' rating lead me to strongly suspect that its an 'Option 1', since transformers are rated in VA.

You should be able to source a suitable replacement locally. The specs you should be most concerned with are the output voltage (12V) and current (no less than 850mA - more is ok).

Comment: Thanks for this info. I've found another adapter 120V AC to 12V DC but it's rated at 1000mA.  Would it be OK as a substitute for the 850mA?  Would I not want one with lower mA but one with higher mA would be OK? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: Yes you have it correct. Higher mA rating on the adapter means it *can* supply more than you need, not that it *will*. Lower rating on the adapter means it might struggle and possibly overheat while trying to supply what your motor wants.

Answer (score 1):

If the marking on the adapter does not give a range of input voltages then you cannot assume that it will work at a voltage so much lower than the rated voltage. You should assume that it will not.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage transformation (from a transformer) is a matter coils/winds in the inductor. 240V --> 12V means that the transformer has 20 coils in the primary winding for every 1 coil in the secondary winding. If you plug your transformer into 120V, I expect that this transformer will have 6V output.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Some types of adapters are multi-voltage, but if so, they tend to brag it.

The multi-voltage type uses electronic switching instead of a heavy transformer, so they tend to feel unnaturally light, compared to the dense transformer units you are accustomed to.  If a transformer is involved, it won't be multi-voltage.